# SQL Speed Up my Update - Left Join in PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, left-join

I am trying to join one dataframe to another using two id's (patient_id, encounter_id) that are shared between them. Both dataframes are indexed on these ids.

Here is the LHS:

```
tnx_prophy=# \d diagnosis
                       Table "public.diagnosis"
            Column             | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------------------------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 patient_id                    | text |           |          |
 encounter_id                  | text |           |          |
 code_system                   | text |           |          |
 code                          | text |           |          |
 principal_diagnosis_indicator | text |           |          |
 date                          | text |           |          |
Indexes:
    "idx_pt_enc_dx" btree (patient_id, encounter_id)
```

Here is the RHS:

```
tnx_prophy=# \d encounter
               Table "public.encounter"
    Column    | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 encounter_id | text |           |          |
 patient_id   | text |           |          |
 type         | text |           |          |
 enc_type     | text |           |          |
Indexes:
    "idx_pt_enc_enc" btree (patient_id, encounter_id)
```

The datasets are large (~500m rows?), but my UPDATE and JOIN function seems to be taking much longer than I would like. And yes, I would like to update (not just generate a temporary table)

```
tnx_prophy=# ALTER TABLE diagnosis ADD COLUMN enc_type text;
ALTER TABLE
tnx_prophy=# UPDATE diagnosis
tnx_prophy-# SET enc_type = encounter.enc_type
tnx_prophy-# FROM encounter
tnx_prophy-# WHERE (diagnosis.patient_id, diagnosis.encounter_id) = (encounter.patient_id, encounter.encounter_id);
```

Any advice on how to do this faster? Or am I messing up the syntax here somehow obvious? Thanks a ton if anyone can help!

Comment: What is the EXPLAIN VERBOSE?  What is your hardware like?

Comment: It will probably be faster to create a new table with the column joined in, then delete and rename and shuffle around foreign keys, etc. to use the new table.

Comment: Both indexes are  *not* `UNIQUE`, so every updated row could be hit by a *partial* Carthesian product. ( you also could avoid the *idempotent* updates)

Comment: And since `(encounter.patient_id, encounter.encounter_id)` is NOT a candidate key for the *source* table, these updates can even produce different values. In short: use PKs (or Unique/candidate keys) and FKs.

Comment: Thank you to both! Hardware is mediocre, dell XPS 13, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10710U CPU @ 1.10GHz, 1608 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: Would it be valuable for me to MAKE the encounter index unique? I've been avoiding SELECT DISTINCT commands because they seem to be very processor intensive

Comment: Why isn't a patient_id / encounter_id combination a candidate key for the source table? They should be shared betweeen tables. What does PK or FK stand for?

Comment: Sorry for rudimentary questions, I have coded in R until now and have had to switch over for large databases. Still picking up SQL

Comment: The *source* table functions as a **lookup** table. It **should yield unique values**, given the look-up *arguments*. I'll add an answer to illustrate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
\i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE diagnosis
        ( patient_id    text
        , encounter_id  text
        -- , code_system        text
        -- , code       text
        , principal_diagnosis_indicator text
        -- , date       text
        );
CREATE INDEX idx_pt_enc_dx ON diagnosis (patient_id, encounter_id);

CREATE TABLE encounter
        ( encounter_id  text
        , patient_id    text
        , type  text
        , enc_type      text
        );
CREATE INDEX idx_pt_enc_enc ON encounter (patient_id, encounter_id);

INSERT INTO diagnosis(patient_id, encounter_id, principal_diagnosis_indicator) VALUES
 (1,1, 'influenza')
,(1,1, 'cancer')
,(2,1, 'influenza')
,(2,1, 'cancer')
        ;
INSERT INTO encounter(patient_id, encounter_id, enc_type) VALUES
 ( 1,1, 'OMG')
,( 1,1, 'WTF')
,( 2,1, 'WTF')
,( 2,1, 'OMG')
        ;

ALTER TABLE diagnosis ADD COLUMN enc_type text;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
UPDATE diagnosis dst
SET enc_type = src.enc_type
FROM encounter src
WHERE (dst.patient_id, dst.encounter_id) = (src.patient_id, src.encounter_id)
AND dst.enc_type IS DISTINCT FROM src.enc_type -- both columns are NULLABLE
        ;

SELECT * FROM diagnosis;
```

---

Result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
INSERT 0 4
INSERT 0 4
ALTER TABLE
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on diagnosis dst  (cost=0.30..47.59 rows=7 width=140) (actual time=0.383..0.385 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.30..47.59 rows=7 width=140) (actual time=0.139..0.232 rows=8 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: ((dst.patient_id = src.patient_id) AND (dst.encounter_id = src.encounter_id))
         Join Filter: (dst.enc_type IS DISTINCT FROM src.enc_type)
         ->  Index Scan using idx_pt_enc_dx on diagnosis dst  (cost=0.15..21.15 rows=520 width=134) (actual time=0.066..0.082 rows=4 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using idx_pt_enc_enc on encounter src  (cost=0.15..21.15 rows=520 width=102) (actual time=0.051..0.086 rows=7 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 1.278 ms
 Execution Time: 0.858 ms
(8 rows)

 patient_id | encounter_id | principal_diagnosis_indicator | enc_type 
------------+--------------+-------------------------------+----------
 1          | 1            | cancer                        | WTF
 1          | 1            | influenza                     | WTF
 2          | 1            | cancer                        | OMG
 2          | 1            | influenza                     | OMG
(4 rows)
```

---

Take a good look at the

`Merge Join  (cost=0.30..47.59 rows=7 width=140) (actual time=0.139..0.232 rows=8 loops=1)`

line: 8 rows are updated, but there are only 4 records!! This happens because the search-key into your *look up table* is not `unique` . Every record is updated twice, (and the order is undefined ...)!

Comment: Next time: don't worry about performance. Worry about correctness first.